# Why 'sacrificing' and what is 'everything' here?

Tags: meaning

Why 'sacrificing' and what is 'everything' here?

> “Believe in something, even if it means **sacrificing everything,**” says
>   a NIKE advertisement released in September. The ad made waves because
>   of the man saying those words: Colin Kaepernick, a former football
>   player. Kaepernick began a series of protests among National Football
>   League players against police violence and racial inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collocation **sacrificing everything** means losing all that you have or all that you have achieved, whatever that may be in your particular circumstances, usually by taking a particular action or expressing a particular opinion publicly.

> Are you sure you want to come out against this military invasion? It is very popular. It would end your political career. You'd be sacrificing everything.